# Ray: first line of example dataset = ray.data.read_csv("s3://anonymous@air-example-data/breast_cancer.csv") errors out

Tags: ray

When trying the Ray AI Runtime Quick Start first line of example code:

```
dataset = ray.data.read_csv("s3://anonymous@air-example-data/breast_cancer.csv")
```

encountered the error below

> AttributeError: module 'grpc._cython.cygrpc' has no attribute
> 'get_working_loop'

Any quick pointer what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

What version of `grpcio` do you have installed? This may be due to an old version.

Comment: grpcio version: 1.41.1

Comment: This should be compatible, but it looks like the python environment might not be sane. Can you try to re-install ray in a new virtual environment?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).